# Select Case in where Condition Help Required

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Select PlotID, PlotName, PT.TypeName, B.BlockName, TownName, P.PricePlot, P.PriceMarla
From Plots P
Left Join PlotType PT ON P.TypeID=PT.TypeID
Left Join Town T ON P.TownID=T.TownID
Left Join Blocks B On p.BlockID=B.BlockID
Where (Case When @IsSold = 'False' Then P.PlotID NOT IN (Select PlotID from SaleContract)
            When @IsSold= 'True' Then P.PlotID IN (Select PlotID from SaleContract)
            END)
```

**Need Help To resolve this query**
In and NOT IN not working in case after where statement, how can i resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

It is best to avoid `case` expressions in the `where` clause.  One reason is that they are easy to avoid by using simpler boolean constructs:

```
Where (@IsSold = 'False' and P.PlotID NOT IN (Select PlotID from SaleContract)) or
      (@IsSold = 'True' and P.PlotID IN (Select PlotID from SaleContract))
```

Note that SQL Server does not support a boolean type, so a boolean expression cannot be returned from a `case`.